# component-based php framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

could someone give an example of the meaning of this word?

i read about that prado is a component-based framework and i wonder if cakephp and codeigniter are too?

Comment: Good response here (not for php though): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1248913/166921

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component based framework basically means that you can pick and choose the elemnts of the system you want without having to refactor those individual elements themselves. Zend Framework is a good example.

Usually the opposite is highly couple framework like CakePHP or RoR. In these cases it is much harder to divorce and individual component like the Router or Controller and use it outside that framework's stack.

In general you want to minimize tight coupling so you get the most out of reuse and have the most flexibility in terms of replacing components or modifying them. The thing i find i often dont like about component frameworks is that while the individual components are often well designed and have a default way of working with each other often a ton of development time isnt poored into automation of using the tools together. Take Zend Framework for example. GREAT COMPONENTS, however with 1.10 we finally see a decent commandline tool to automate setup and initialization of modules/controllers/views etc.. There wanst a defined bootstrapping process/convention until 1.8 i think it was... For me this is one of the most important parts. Something highly boasted by RoR, Django, Cake, Symfony, CodeIgniter and others.

Comment: are cakephp and codeigniter component based? could you give an example of some components on a webpage? and why did the creator of prado created a new one, yii. was prado not the right way to go?

Comment: Cake definitely is NOT. CodeIgniter and Prado/Yii ive never used so i cant comment.