# Component based MVC: what does mean "event-driven"

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsf, spring-mvc

I've work with JSP and Spring MVC. I've strong understanding of what is request/response MVC frameworks. But I read the next phrase  and I have the single question about component based MVC.

**Phrase:**

> There are two main types of web layer implementations:
>   request/response frameworks and component frameworks... Some
>   frameworks, such as Tapestry and JavaServer Faces (JSF), are
>   considered component-based... Those frameworks are essentially
>   EVENT-DRIVEN, as the components respond to events originally coming
>   from the web layer.

**Question:** *What does mean event driven?* Does it mean that instead of handling URL through controller (like in Spring MVC) I can hang a separate listener to each specific element on the page (i.e. form)?

Comment: event driven means that a next step is 'triggered', or started, by an event.

for instance: clicking a button, receiving a message, ..
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming

Comment: @Stultuske that I know. But what does that mean in WEB. In some sense, in Spring MVC when we push the button it also cause some events. Is it event driven?

Comment: you should look on some jsf codes.How it calls function in some manage d bean.basically jsf provides ui components like editor,date selector etc on which you bind your events to some function. see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247627/java-component-based-vs-request-based-frameworks

Comment: @guanu thanks, but I'd seen that topic before I wrote this question. That topic doesn't provide answer to my question. Do you mean I should learn JSF to make it clear for me?